# How to sync ASP.NET MVC calendar control to Outlook

Tags: asp.net, outlook

Does anyone know of a way to sync outlook calendar to custom control? The custom control is shared by all users on a web page, but each user has access to his meeting using outlook. I have searched a couple of controls and the only way to do this was by using ics files, I would like to have all this done programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your organization uses MS Exchange and your version supports it you could look at using the Exchange web service api.  Here's a link for the [Exchange 2010 SDK docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd877012%28EXCHG.140%29).

Comment: It's actually an older version of Exhange but thanks. Ill try to see if the older version has a usable SDK, though I have found nothing thru google.